# How can I repair my porch column which has separated at the top?

Tags: porch

One of my three front porch columns has separated at the top. Wonder what could be the cause and if this is an easy fix/reassembly or requires replacement? Also who should I call? I’ve reached out to carpenters and contractors who haven’t gotten back.

Comment: With no pictures can only give wild guesses.

Comment: Definitely needs an [edit] to include an overview picture of the porch as well as some detailed (focused and well lit) pics of the column separation to have the slightest clue.

Comment: If the contractors you've contacted aren't getting back to you, keep calling new ones. (You don't want to badger one of them into accepting the job only to have him be really hard to get hold of once you've signed the contract.)